# jquery mobile load new page return error

Tags: html, mobile

I make a test.html file like below:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <!--Head of the main web-->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h2><img src="pic/jquery-logo.png" alt="1"></h2>
    </div>


    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <!--3 row navbar--!>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">first</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">third</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!--first nav bar of the 3-->
            <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="order.html"><img src="pic/business_standard_room.png"></a></li>        
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="two">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-alt-icon">
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="three">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">  
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!--footer of the page-->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h5>Powered by Atek</h5>
    </div>

</div>
```

I put the order.html and the test.html in the same folder.but when I click the link in the first tab.it returns me error.here is the error the chrome developer console showed

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///media/IRM_CCSA_X6/Mobile%20Website/Hotel/order.html.       Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile uses AJAX for the navigation inside the website, so when you press the link an AJAX call is done in order to get the new page.

I suppose that you are not using a server to test your website (just the `file:///` protocol), and I think that is the problem. It has been reported [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) that local files are not loaded correctly using AJAX on Chrome, so you should use other browser or deploy a server to test it on Chrome.

Or in case you don't want to use the AJAX navigation, you could add the atribute `data-ajax` to the link in order to disable it:

```
<a href="order.html" data-ajax="false">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah,I googled for the problem.It's problem of the Chrome Emulator.